# Capture middle directory and redirect to new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

The URL I'm working with is something like this...

old-website/directory/sub-directory/last-directory

I need to capture just the **sub-directory** portion and then use that in a URL for a redirect. For example, redirect to new-website/working/sub-directory/page

However, I also need a redirect that works for old-website/directory/sub-directory to redirect to the same new-website/working/sub-directory/page

Comment: Please show us some code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/directory/([^/]+)(?:/.*)?$ http://working/$1/page
```

Change 302 to 301 once you verify that rule is working fine.